# "The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets" error while using mongodb-source-connect

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I get an error when running kafka-mongodb-source-connect
I was trying to run **connect-standalone** with `connect-avro-standalone.properties` and `MongoSourceConnector.properties` so that Connect write data which is written in MongoDB to Kafka topic.

This is what I wanted to do

```sh
bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties share/confluent-hub-components/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb/etc/MongoSourceConnector.properties
```

**connect-avro-standalone.properties**

```
# Sample configuration for a standalone Kafka Connect worker that uses Avro serialization and
# integrates the the Schema Registry. This sample configuration assumes a local installation of
# Confluent Platform with all services running on their default ports.

# Bootstrap Kafka servers. If multiple servers are specified, they should be comma-separated.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data.
# Every Connect user will need to configure these based on the format they want their data in
# when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified,
# but most users will always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never
# visible outside of Connect in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# Local storage file for offset data
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

# Confluent Control Center Integration -- uncomment these lines to enable Kafka client interceptors
# that will report audit data that can be displayed and analyzed in Confluent Control Center
# producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
# consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor

# These are provided to inform the user about the presence of the REST host and port configs
# Hostname & Port for the REST API to listen on. If this is set, it will bind to the interface used to listen to requests.
#rest.host.name=
#rest.port=8083

# The Hostname & Port that will be given out to other workers to connect to i.e. URLs that are routable from other servers.
#rest.advertised.host.name=
#rest.advertised.port=

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include
# any combination of:
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Examples:
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
# Replace the relative path below with an absolute path if you are planning to start Kafka Connect from within a
# directory other than the home directory of Confluent Platform.
plugin.path=share/java,/Users/anton/Downloads/confluent-5.3.2/share/confluent-hub-components
```

**MongoSourceConnecor.properties**

```
name=mongo-source
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# Connection and source configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=test
collection=test
```

This is the error:

```java
[2020-01-02 18:55:11,546] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40573 (Location40573): 'The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets", "code": 40573, "codeName": "Location40573"}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Debezium Mongo connector instead?

Comment: Have not yet. I am not sure if Mongo database without a replica set is working with Connector. I will make a replica set, try again and check whether it works or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> stage is only supported on replica sets

You need to [make your Mongo database a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set) in order to read the oplog

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243780/converting-mongodb-instance-from-standalone-to-replica-set-and-backing-up

Comment: Ah ! . yes i got it.

mongodb-kafka-source connector is using oplog for writing data in Kafka so a replica set Mongo database is mandatory option.

**Thanks a lot Cricket**

Comment: @cricket_007/@Anton: Hi, do you have this set up somewhere on github?
I have a similar case to implement where I have to capture MongoDB-ChangeStream to Kafka connector and then to Kafka Broker. And from Kafka Broker Java Service would process the change-stream event.
How do you install MongoDB-Kafka-Source-Connector?

Answer (score 31):

MongoDB change streams option is available only in replica sets setup. However, you can update your standalone installation to a single node replica set by following the below steps.

1. Locate the `mongodb.conf` file and add the replica set details

Add the following replica set details to `mongodb.conf` file

> ```
> replication:
>   replSetName: "<replica-set name>"
> ```

Example

> replication:   replSetName: "rs0"

Note: Location in brew installed MongoDB /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

2. Initiate the replica set using `rs.initiate()`

Login to the MongoDB shell and run command `rs.initiate()` this will start your replica set. Logs look like the following on successful start

```
> rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1577545731, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1577545731, 1)
}
```

That's all with these two simple steps you are running a MongoDB replica set with one node only.

Reference: https://onecompiler.com/posts/3vchuyxuh/enabling-replica-set-in-mongodb-with-just-one-node

Comment: worked very well for me

Comment: brew config file is now under /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 1):

This is helped in my situation (`macOS` env), see [more](https://medium.com/@mfkenson/locally-run-mongodb-4-2-replica-set-on-macos-6117f2ae088e):

I. Install Zero-config MongoDB runner. Starts a replica set with no non-Node dependencies, not even MongoDB.

```
npm install -g run-rs   // OR yarn global add run-rs
```

II. Use connection string

```
mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/YOUR_DB_NAME?replicaSet=rs&retryWrites=false
```